# jpa how to join fetch entity in map key or value

Tags: jpa, join

jpa how to join fetch entity in map key or value? For example,

```
@Entity
public class Store {
     @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     Map<Merchandise, Integer> inventory;
}
```

JPQL

```
select s from Store s left join fetch s.inventory
```

How to specify the lazy fetch type for map key (Merchandise)?
How to join fetch the map key (Merchandise)?

Comment: The fetch is about the collection, not about the Key or value. BTW, isn't the same things?

Comment: Map key (e.g. Entity) can be lazy. For example. Merchandise (map key type) has a property product (Entity), how to tell JPA to fetch the attribute product?

Comment: were you able to pull this out?